# Stick navigation bar delay

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

This issue I just can't wrap my head around. The nav. bar on http://digitalblare.com stickies to the top of the page and scrolls up and down with the user, but there's a delay of at least 10 seconds before it does it.

Basically once the page loads, for the first 10+ seconds the navbar does not sticky, but after 10 seconds it will sticky if you scroll and function perfectly fine until the page or another page on the site is loaded.

I'm decently fluent in HTML and CSS, but know very little Javascript / PHP / jquery (which is what I assume is behind the navbar sticky effect), so am not sure which code I should reproduce here.

Comment: Sounds like your site is waiting to load. Do you have say, adds that need to be loaded on the page? That may cause a delay in other scripts to be run.

Comment: Your site is too heavy. And navbar initialize start after when all resources loaded. Site need codereview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is too basic, but by any chance are you looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/myTerminal/D6a6K/?

You could use `setTimeout` to add a delay.

If the above fits fine, you may add a transition time to make it look like an animation.